# Using Featured Image as Hero Background

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm trying to create a user-friendly way to choose a hero image AND leave the ability to edit a text overlay in the same div. Here's the problem:

A. Featured image code is php, and in the template.

B. Editable text is in the editor.

I don't want to enable php in pages for security reasons, and I don't want clients having to edit templates to change a text overlay. I want to combine them, so they can edit the text in the editor and choose a Featured Image in the editor and somehow put them together. I just can't see a way to get it done.

Edit:
I'm familiar with PHP/HTML/CSS, have been using WP since 1.0, and create custom themes for my clients. I'm not looking for free code, but for ideas on how to add functionality without compromising security. I don't know if this specific idea is possible without enabling PHP in pages, which I'd like to avoid.

Edit: I assume this will stay on hold until it's approved or deleted. I'm responding here because I wouldn't know where else to do it. This question is definitely about WordPress development...it's using a post thumbnail elsewhere in a WP installation. I suppose one could use the same info in another context, but this is a WP question. If you have feedback on how to make the question acceptable, please let me know.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done any research? Have you tried creating your own template at all? Are you familiar with PHP/HTML/CSS? This isn't just a place to get free code...

Comment: Voted to keep the question closed, because the question is not clear. The way it is stated now, this looks like a php question on how to insert an image and a text in a template. I get the feeling you are trying to say something else, but I don't know what.

Comment: I wouldn't mind reopening this with a bit more clarification. Are you not familiar with how `the_post_thumbnail()` and `the_content()` work in templates? It's unclear what code exactly you're looking for.

Comment: If the overlay is simple text then I'd look at adding a text input to the Featured Image Metabox in the admin.  If the text must have some HTML (maybe it's a heading, caption & link), then I'd add a new Metabox for those fields.

Comment: Thanks.

How the_post_thumbnail() and the_content() work is basic stuff, covered in the Codex. I want to combine template stuff and editor stuff. 

If [#hero] is in the template, it's not in the editor. I want users to select a thumbnail for [#hero] and edit text for [#hero] without editing the template.

I could do a workaround with CSS to absolutely position a div in the editor over a div in the template, but that seems both limiting and overly complex. 

Andy's response is helpful. I'm just looking for suggestions on how to make more complex elements more user-friendly.

Comment: @GodWords Allowing the user to layer multiple elements gets into broad territory. If it was simply Text on a single background image, you could use the Featured Image and Editor to do this and position this yourself in the templates so it's always displayed the same. They edit the text or update the image and it reflects on the front-end. If you need to do positioning and previewing it's going to get complicated fast. It's in this case that an out of the box solution is probably going to be your best bet unless you have time to spend developing a complex solution.